# Error vapply(df, class, FUN.VALUE = NA_character_) : values must be length 1, but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 3 (when running a LCA in R)

Tags: r

I am using Mplusautomation to run a LCA with a distal outcome in R. Both the indicators and the distal are ordinal variables, with scales ranging from 1 to 5 for the indicator variables and 1 to 4 for the distal variables.

```
  TITLE = "BCH lca with distal outcome;", 
  
  DATA = "LISTWISE=ON;",
  
  VARIABLE = 
    "usevar = int_3 sw_3 soc_3 alt_3 gov_3 for_3;
    auxiliary = claim_5 claim_6 (bch);
    classes = c(5);",
  
  ANALYSIS =
    "estimator = mlr;
    type = mixture;
    starts = 500 100;
    processors = 10;",
  
  OUTPUT = 
    "type = plot3;
    series = int_3 sw_3 soc_3 alt_3 gov_3 for_3(*);",
  
  usevariables = c("int_3", "sw_3", "soc_3", "alt_3", "gov_3", "for_3", "claim_5", "claim_6"),
  rdata =  data_lca_distal_Mpanel_220918)

m_bch_fit <- mplusModeler(m_bch,
                          dataout=here("paper 2"),
                          modelout=here("paper 2"),
                          check=TRUE, run = TRUE, hashfilename = FALSE)
```

However, when I run the code I get the following error message:

*Error in vapply(df, class, FUN.VALUE = NA_character_) :
values must be length 1,
but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 3*

I am new to Mplus and R and have no idea what this error means. I extracted the indicators to a data frame without NA's, and to a data frame with NA = -99 (defining MISSING ARE ALL -99 in the code). However, that did not work and the error still appears. Does anyone know why this error appears and what I can do about it? I really appreciate any help on this matter.

Thank you!

Comment: This happens when R tries to store a vector of length 3 in pre-allocated space with only length one. Seems like a bug somewhere in `mplusModeler` or the functions it calls internally. It might be worth to [directly address the author](https://github.com/michaelhallquist/MplusAutomation/issues).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Will try to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I am also new to the MPlusAutomation package, but I ran into a similar issue when using the prepareMPlusData() command. I found [this ticket](https://github.com/michaelhallquist/MplusAutomation/issues/161) on GitHub that pointed to the issue for me--when I looked at the dataframe I called in the command, I discovered that the variables in the dataframe had multiple class() objects (3 to be exact) which lined up with my error code as well. I simply converted my dataframe to a matrix and back and this resolved the issue. Try putting this before you define m_bch:

```
data_lca_distal_Mpanel_220918<-as.data.frame(as.matrix(data_lca_distal_Mpanel_220918))
```

Comment: Only `as.data.frame` didn't work?

Comment: Not for me. That did not strip off the class data at the variable level like the as.matrix command does. The conversion to a matrix and then a dataframe did it! This is definitely a workaround, though, so I hope to see improvements to the library in the future.

Comment: I see. After `as.matrix` you have a single class in the variables though. Did you know that you may directly manipulate the `class(data) <- "data.frame"`?

Comment: From what I understand, the MplusAutomation error happens precisely because there is more than one class among the variables. How might you directly manipulate the classes of the variables in the dataframe using that command? Is there a way to strip away 2 of the 3 classes with it in our example?

Comment: Too long for a comment, please see my answer for an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this little data frame,

```
dat
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  4  7
# 2  2  5  8
# 3  3  6  9
```

where:

```
lapply(dat, class)
# $X1
# [1] "integer"         "important class"
# 
# $X2
# [1] "integer"          "other class"      "else other class"
# 
# $X3
# [1] "integer"          "other class"      "else other class"
```

We could `lapply` over it and check whether a variable `inherits` from a specific class and get a boolean `u`,

```
(u <- sapply(dat, inherits, c('other class')))
#    X1    X2    X3 
# FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

with which we subset the data frame and rebuild the `structure` just using the first `class(x)[1]`,

```
dat[u] <- lapply(dat[u], \(x)structure(x, class=class(x)[1]))
dat
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  4  7
# 2  2  5  8
# 3  3  6  9
```

where:

```
lapply(dat, class)

[1] "integer"         "important class"

$X2
[1] "integer"

$X3
[1] "integer"
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(X1 = structure(1:3, class = c("integer", "important class"
)), X2 = structure(4:6, class = c("integer", "other class", "else other class"
)), X3 = structure(7:9, class = c("integer", "other class", "else other class"
))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after I imported DTA format data into R. The solution I found is to remove all value labels using labelled::remove_val_labels(). Sometimes survey labels mess up with many R functions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).